# Flutter: Disable Tab Navigation Until form validation complete

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I am Developing a signup form in flutter, I want to have it in Tabs but scroll/navigation should be disabled unless current tab contents are validated correctly. I have given a thought to have floating action button and validating tab contents in onPressed function, But Not sure if this is right way to do it and is there a better and elegant alternative for this.

Link for screenshot of form
[signup form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sYfI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using tab in this situation is a bad practice. I suggest you use the horizontal stepper. You can check the official documentation from [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html), example with form fields [here](https://medium.com/flutterpub/steppers-and-form-in-flutter-49cda857230c) and [here](https://github.com/nisrulz/flutter-examples/tree/master/using_stepper).